# How to find nodes at distance less than n from the given node?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

In theory, I can use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the distances of all nodes, but if I have a big graph, I will waste a lot of time for calculating distances to remote nodes. Is there some more effecient algorithm?

Comment: Does the graph have any known feature? Like non-cyclic graph or edges with positive cost?

Comment: It is an undirected weighted graph with positive weights, with no loops.

Answer (score 2):

If the edges aren't weighted (or equivalently, if they all have the same weight), you can just run a breadth-first search until the required depth.  If they *are* weighted, Dijkstra's algorithm is your best choice: it also explores nodes in order of increasing distance from the start vertex, so just stop it once the next vertex found is further away than your maximum allowed distance.

Comment: This is why an understanding of an algorithm is so important, it lets you work out how to modify it slightly to tailor it to your own scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modified breadth-first-search for this (even for weighted graphs).

```
listNodes(node start , int maxRange)
    list queue
    set visited
    add(queue , start)
    add(visited , start)

    while ! isEmpty(queue)
        pair p = remove(queue , 0)

        int distTmp = p.dist
        node n = p.node

        //only neighbours that haven't yet been visited
        for node next in disjoint(listNeighbours(n) , visited)
            add(visited , next)//mark as visited
            //store the node in the queue with the distance to start as attribute
            add(queue , pair(next , distTmp + distance(n , next)))

    return visited
```

If the graph isn't weighted, `distance(node , node)` will always return 1 for neighbournodes.